# smooth transition between css animations

Tags: css, rotation, transition, keyframe

I'm currently coding an expandable box and after defeating the on-off-hover glitch I realized that there's one particular situation in which I cannot get my plus to behave the way I want.

The code can be found below:
http://codepen.io/Sandypandy/pen/Fyuxf

The aforementioned case: when I hover over the circle when it's closed, click it and take my cursor out immediately, the plus rotates a bit and then roughly jumps straight to desired position (works perfectly fine and smooth though when I hover over the circle, click it and keep the cursor inside).

I'll be very grateful for any advice.
Cheers,
E.

Comment: I see the reason is that  when your mouse enters, the rotation starts at 360 and ends at 0... the same if the mouse leave, it starts at 360 and ends at 0.   so if the mouse happens to leave when the rotation is at only 270 or so... it would jerk right back to 360 and start the rotation over again.

Comment: lemme see if there is a differnt way... please hold...[music]

Comment: I rather do understand the reason of this behavior, I just don't really have any idea how to get rid of it in any way. I was trying to put other rotate values, but it still seems not to be working, sadly. Thanks for help, by the way :)

Comment: Now what do you want to be the plus ? I am not clear about your problem ?

Comment: The plus transforms into x after clicking on the container and all of this works fine. I just don't want it to roughly skip the rest of the rotation, but I want it to finish the animation smoothly - never mind if the cursor is still inside or already outside of this circle.

Comment: I fixed the jerky rotation... but now i broke the rotation that happens on expand...  take a look and maybe you can figure it out from there....http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aFbwg

Comment: actually it technically still works on expand... but it seems to be a bit touchy depending on exactly where you click.'

Comment: Oh well, previously it always ended up in the x position, now it's pretty much random. Guess I'll have to spend some more time on it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: i think i fixed it 100% see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer i am pretty sure

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DzFyr

basically I removed all the references to the "unhovered" state in the css and the javascript...  And in the "click toggle" part of your js, I made sure that the "hovered" class is removed before the "clicked" class is toggled.

I think there were just too many unneccessary properties that were conflicting with each other.

the moral of the story is you dont always need to define a specific mouse in mouse out behavior.  CSS Transition will help smoothly transition between the original state and the end state... and back again.

Comment: I think I used the additional class on mouse out to prevent the first animation on load (might have used this solution somewhere else earlier and it worked, so gave it a shot in here as well). Anyways, this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish (and failed...). Thanks!

Comment: Well, the good news is that you coded everything you needed more or less correctly... just needed a little optimizing ;)